# Unable to click rotationally on different items in order to scrape the name from their innerpages

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script using selenium to visit a site, click on few show more buttons in order to unveil all the containers and finally iterate through the items to reach it's inner page to grab the title from there.

[website link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1LHREtq6LL55eZjeelzSg3OhT2Q4oHPJ4&ll=21.641800756641153%2C-89.81278699953181&z=2)

So, these are the steps I'm doing using the script:

1. [show more button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax2DB.jpg)
2. [different items from containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GhCw.jpg)
3. [item name from innerpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns75X.jpg)

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1LHREtq6LL55eZjeelzSg3OhT2Q4oHPJ4&ll=21.641800756641153%2C-89.81278699953181&z=2"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)

# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class][index]"))).click()

for show_more in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[./span[@contains(.,' more')]]/span"))):
    show_more.click()

for i,item in enumerate(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class][index]")))):
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class][index]")[i]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",elem)
    item_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='qqvbed-p83tee-lTBxed']"))).text
    print(item_name)
    driver.back()
```

There is a commented out line within the script which when uncommented works if i click on a single item. However, it fails when I use it in a loop. The click on show more button doesn't work at all and throws `TimeoutException` error.

***How can I click cyclically on different items in order to scrape the name from their innerpages?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues with your code:

1. Xpath you have used to click *show More* under ports and terminal is wrong. See the correct one I have used.
2. driver.back is making your full page load, which is causing slowness and rendering issue. Instead click back button on panel opened after you are opening port details and etc.

Also I have included code to scroll to element before clicking it

See full code as below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1LHREtq6LL55eZjeelzSg3OhT2Q4oHPJ4&ll=21.641800756641153%2C-89.81278699953181&z=2"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get(link)

for show_more in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),' more')]"))):
    show_more.click()

for i, item in enumerate(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class][index]")))):
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class][index]")[i]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem) #Scroll to Link before click
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
    item_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='qqvbed-p83tee-lTBxed']"))).text
    print(item_name)
    time.sleep(0.5) # To make sure Back button is notoverlapping sometime with image above
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Directions to here']//parent::div//preceding-sibling::div//div[@aria-label='Back']"))).click()
```

**Note :**  Xpath you have used to print item_Name is not correct as in few cases it is returning empty value. I did not change it as I am not sure if its desired or not.

*Out Put:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I mistakenly used `@` sign with `contain()` within the xpath defined to locate show more button. However, it should work If that sign is kicked out from there. Usually `driver.back()` works in such cases but I didn't find it working here. The last line that you used in your script is the main trick I suppose. Thanks a lot @rahul rai for your amazing solution.